# What are the potential issues with changing an API function parameter from 'char *' to 'const char *'?

Tags: c++

If I have an API function declaration like this:

```
void fn(char * s);
```

and I change it in a later revision to:

```
void fn(const char * s);
```

Does this break binary compatibility? Could this break something that worked before? Are there any issues with this type of change?

Note that the argument was always treated as a const, even in the first revision.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a dynamically linked libraries. If so, it depends on your platform. The c++ language itself doesn't say much about binary compatibility. Please specify the platform you are asking about.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux While it may technically be implementation-dependent, practically all implementations use name mangling to implement overloaded functions, which will thus result in incompatibility.

Comment: Could you not simply add an overload?

Comment: For C++ code, it would be a breaking binary change but not necessarily a breaking source code change. You should bump your library's major version number and document the change.

Comment: In theory yes, in practice no

Answer (score 3):

If the function is declared extern "C" it likely won't matter, if not it probably will.

For C++ functions the parameter types are part of the signature so the mangled name will be different for a function taking a `const char *` and one that takes a simple `char *`. And because of that name resolution would fail without rebuilding the code.

C, however, does not encode parameter types so the name would be the same either way.

The actual code would likely be the same in either case, the fact that it's a `char *` won't change how the elements are accessed as compared with a `const char *`.

Comment: You might want to mention that the reason the parameter types are encoded is because you can have different overloads of a function based on whether the argument is `const`.

Answer (score 1):

`void fn(char * s)` and `void fn(const char * s)` are absolutely different functions in C++. It's the same as changing its name. You definitely should save the old one but redirect it to the new.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct silly{
  operator char*()const{ return 0;}
  operator char const*() const{ return "hello"; }
};
```